# mysql: inner query is not working inside selectif statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, select, join

I want result for below query be Y if Email is blacklisted, else run the inner query and return the specific facility Name.

```
Select if (EmailBlacklisted = 'Y', 'Y', 
     'select a.facilityname from facility a
     inner join domainfacility b on a.facility_ID=b.facility_facility_ID
      inner join domain c on b.domain_Domain_ID = c.Domain_ID 
     where a.facilitystatus="A" and c.DomainName = "cd.com" ') 
from domain where DomainName= 'cd.com';
```

BUT query returning same inner query as RESULT if emailBlacklisted is N in Domain table. please help

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would approach this just by returning the facility names:

```
select f.facilityname
from facility f inner join
     domainfacility df
     on a.facility_ID = b.facility_facility_ID inner join
     domain d
     on df.domain_Domain_ID = d.Domain_ID 
     where f.facilitystatus = 'A' and d.DomainName = 'cd.com'
where d.DomainName = 'cd.com' and d.EmailBlacklisted <> 'Y';
```

Then, if this returns nothing, that would suggest being blacklisted.  You could just return `Y` for such names:

```
select (case when d.EmailBlacklisted = 'Y' then 'Y' else f.facilityname end)
from facility f inner join
     domainfacility df
     on a.facility_ID = b.facility_facility_ID inner join
     domain d
     on df.domain_Domain_ID = d.Domain_ID 
     where f.facilitystatus = 'A' and d.DomainName = 'cd.com'
where d.DomainName = 'cd.com';
```

But that seems a strange confusion of mixing names with flags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(d.EmailBlacklisted = 'Y', 'Y', a.facilityname)
FROM domain d
LEFT OUTER JOIN domainfacility b ON b.domain_Domain_ID = d.Domain_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN facility a ON b.facility_facility_ID = a.facility_ID AND a.facilitystatus = 'A'
WHERE d.DomainName= 'cd.com';
```